# SqlException was unhandled C#

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to create a Sign Up form. But when I click on the sign up button, I get the exception `SqlException was unhandled`. Almost my whole code is working correct but I'm getting the exception at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Here is my code:-

```
private void buttonSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (check())
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Suhail\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Login(Name,Username,Password,[Mobile No.],Email,SecurityQuestion,Answer) values('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtUsername.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtMobileNo.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + comboSecurityQuestion.Text + "','" + txtAnswer.Text + "');", con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Sign Up Successful.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }

    public bool check()
    {
        Regex name = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        Regex username = new Regex("^[0-9a-zA-Z]+${3}");
        Regex mobileno = new Regex("^[0-9]{10}");
        Regex email = new Regex("^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\\.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$");
        if (name.IsMatch(txtName.Text))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name has to contain characters.");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUsername.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username cannot be left empty.");
        }
        if (username.IsMatch(txtUsername.Text))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username entered is invalid.");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password cannot be left empty.");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtConfirmPassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Confirm Password cannot be left empty.");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMobileNo.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mobile No. cannot be left empty.");
        }
        if (mobileno.IsMatch(txtMobileNo.Text))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mobile No. entered is Invalid.");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Email cannot be left empty.");
        }
        else if (email.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Email entered is invalid.");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAnswer.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Answer to Security Question cannot be left empty.");
        }
        if (name.IsMatch(txtName.Text) && username.IsMatch(txtUsername.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPassword.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtConfirmPassword.Text) && mobileno.IsMatch(txtMobileNo.Text) && email.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAnswer.Text))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the details of the exception then... look at the full stack trace, any inner exceptions, etc.

Comment: Oh, and *use parameterized SQL*. Don't do *anything* else until you've fixed the giant security hole you've got there at the moment. You should pretty much *never* build SQL like this to include values directly.

Comment: what does the exception say?

Comment: Is 'Mobile No.' a valid column name? Enclosing it in square brackets may render it perfectly valid but I've never seen anyone do such a thing... Just looks odd to me

Comment: The exception says that: Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ');'.

Comment: And yes [Mobile No.] works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameterized SQL. Maybe the string you enter contains the ' character and it breaks your query

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Login(Name,Username,Password,[Mobile No.],Email,SecurityQuestion,Answer) values(@Name,@Username,@Password,@Mobile,@Email,@Combosecurity,@Answer);", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",txtPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile",txtMobileNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Combosecurity", comboSecurityQuestion.Text );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answer",txtAnswer.Text);
```

Comment: Ok will try it and let you know.

Comment: I got the message Sign Up Successful now but the data is not getting entered into the database.

Comment: int isSuccessful = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(isSuccessful.ToString());

Try this code so we can see if it was successful.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns int.
For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Comment: Oh I got the error. It was in the Combosecurity in the code. Its working now. Thanks a lot :D